# Вернуть данные в виде JSON

Tags: json, javascript

JSON.parse стандартный метод js ? Есть ли в спецификации ?

И еще вопрос:

Хочу данные возвращать в виде JSON.
Т.е. массив объектов.

На сервер у меня в БД храниться названия книг и id.

Сервер возвращает такую строку:

Делаю это так (не уверен что правильно):
    Переменная W хранит строку:

```
{   
data:
    [
        {
            id:"2",
            name:"TCP / IP"
        },
        {
            id:"34",
            name:"JSSSS"
        },
        {
            id:"55",
            name:"PASCAL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Теперь нужно через eval создать объект.

```
var O = eval(W);
alert(typeof O.data); // undefined
```

Comment: >языки программирования для windows

Специально пересмотрел всю свою активность за всё время пребывпния на ХК. Что-то не увидел у себя такого вопроса. Я пишу только для Android на самом Android-девайсе, никакой речи о Windows быть не модет. Давайте тогда уж ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: начиная с ES5 [вот так](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12)

Comment: @PESIK, у вас JSON не валидный. Воспользуйтесь http://json.parser.online.fr/, увидите, что ни eval ваш, ни JSON.parse не сработают, оба свалятся с ошибками. поэтому на выходе вы получите undefined.

И ошибка будет:
> Property name (in double quotes) expected: data